# View isn't updating with new variable data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using RC3 and I've set a variable of an object and this doesn't update on the view. I'm retrieving an object from Google which takes some time to retrieve.

On the pre-RC versions the view would update automatically when Google returned the result.

Specifically here is the code that I am using to retrieve an object from Google. **The console print out shows the data returned from Google, but the view does not update to represent the change.**

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [p1],
    destinations: [p2],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
        let googDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2);
        return Math.round(googDist / 1000 *10)/10;
    } else {
        //console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
        this.car.drivingDistance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; 
     }
});
console.log(this.car.drivingDistance);
```

The console shows the result from Google, but the view does not update.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please share the template code to display the data

Comment: {{ car.drivingDistance }}

Comment: Pretty basic Angular stuff. Don't see how it helps the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [p1],
    destinations: [p2],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, (response, status) => {
    if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
        let googDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2);
        return Math.round(googDist / 1000 *10)/10;
    } else {
        //console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
        return response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; 
     }
});
```

Calling functions like this in TypeScript are replaced with `() => { }`